# How to slightly offset pasted components when calling PasteFromClipboard() in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

If I am using Delphi at design time, then when I copy/paste a group of components at design time, the pasted components are slightly offset from their originals.

However, I am developing a GUI which allows users to develop a GUI for another app. When I cut/paste the pasted components lie directly over the originals. Is there are way to offset them slightly?

Comment: Can you please specify a bit more how exactly you copy/paste your components in your code - maybe some lines of code would help too.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply, thanks.  I use the CopyToClipboard() and PasteFromClipboard() methods, *but*, these are TMS components, so maybe I ought to ask TMS. I just assumed that they were inherited methods ...

Comment: No need to assume. You have all the source code, at least for the Delphi controls, so check it out. You should notice that the base VCL controls don't generally have any clipboard-related methods. If they do, it's for dealing with their *text contents*. Copy a TEdit to the clipboard, and you get its text; you don't get a copy of the entire control. Asking TMS-related questions here is fine, but you still need to provide more detail. TMS has *lots* of components; which ones are you using?

Comment: Thanks, Rob (+1) Having looked at the code I have decided to ask TMS.

Comment: Rob, maybe you want to "phrase you comment in the manner of an answer" and I'll award you the question ...

Comment: Good idea to ask TMS directly - typically Bruno and his colleagues are very repsonsive.

Comment: Mawg, if I posted that comment as an answer, I'd get voted down for not answering the question. It does absolutely nothing to address the issue of how to change the location of pasted components, which is what you asked for. I have no idea how to do that. I know how I'd go about *learning* how to do that, but I wouldn't consider that a very useful answer. If you ask TMS and you get a more direct technique than the one in Deltics's answer, be sure to relay the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the basic copy/paste working, the next bit is a fairly simple extension to what you already have.

Pasting does of course - presumably - paste the copied controls with their copied property values, so yes they will over-lay on top of the original controls from which they were copied.

To get off-setting behaviour, you will have to do some "nudging" of the pasted controls *after* they have been pasted.  If you cannot get a list of the pasted controls more directly, then one way to derive such a list would be to take a copy of the **Components** collection of the target form before pasting, then after pasting iterate over the **Components** collection once again - any item now in the collection and not in the "original" list must have been pasted and you can apply your Left/Top nudges to those as required.

```
  list := TList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to Pred(dest.ComponentCount) do
      list.Add(dest.Components[i]);

    // Do your pasting

    for i := 0 to Pred(dest.ComponentCount) do
      if list.IndexOf(dest.Components[i]) = -1 then
        // Nudge dest.Components[i]
  finally
    list.Free;
  end;
```

That should get you at least heading down the right direction I think.

NOTE: The above code assumes you are dealing (potentially) with **TComponent** derived classes (i.e. non-visual components).  If you are dealing only with **TControl** descendants then you could optimise by working with the **ControlCount** and **Controls** of the destination container control (not necessarily the form).

Also, the Left/Top position of a **TComponent** is stored in the lo/hi word of the public **DesignInfo** property, so your nudge code will need to take that into account and deal with **TComponent** derived controls differently from **TControl** if you are working with non-visual components as well as visual controls.